# how to validate that email used during registration ends in a specific format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm using this inside my user.rb model

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

However, I would like to only allow certain email addresses. Email addresses that end in `.org` for example. How can I validate this correctly?

I only want to allow all email addresses that end in `.org`
that includes `@department.xyz.org`, basically any variation that is between `@` and `.org`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(previous answer):

```
exp = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.\.]*xyz\.com\z/i 

"asd@yz.com" =~ exp
 => nil 
"asd@xyz.com" =~ exp
 => 0 
"asd@a.xyz.com" =~ exp
 => 0
```

and to get only the e-mails that finishes with org:

```
exp = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.org\z/i 
 => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.org\z/i 
"asd@a.xyz.com" =~ exp
 => nil 
"asd@a.xyz.org" =~ exp
 => 0
```

Comment: I made a quick update to my question to be more specific. What about if it's just .org? I only want to allow .org email addresses. I don't need the xyz validation

Comment: for future reference, if I want to expand and allow email addresses that end in `.ac.uk`, how can I add to that regex?

Comment: The tail of the email is on the `\.org` in the regexp I wrote. So if you want to mathc with `.ac.uk` just replace the `\.org` with `\.ac\.uk`.